# Git — tracking the moving of already tracked files

Tags: git, mercurial

Mercurial has a single command `addr` that stages both added and removed paths, so it is able to track the moving of a given file to a different path in the directory.

To do this in Git, I find I have to use two separate commands:

`git add -u <path>`

will note the disappearance of those files from their original path, and then

`git add <path>`

will note their appearance somewhere else.

But there doesn't seem to be a one-step equivalent to Mercurial's `addr` command. Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Git has a move command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mv.html) that can be used to move files/folders:

```
git mv <file or directory> <destination>
```

You can also use the `--all` or `-A` flag of `add` to update both new files and removed files in the index

```
git add -A
```

From the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for `git add`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html) (emphasis mine):

> ```
> -A
> --all
> ```
>
> Like `-u`, but match `<filepattern>` against files in the working tree in addition to the index. That means that **it will find new files as well as staging modified content and removing files that are no longer in the working tree**.

Comment: `git mv` is fine if the file hasn't been moved yet; Git will move it for me. But I prefer to use regular command-line tools and then turn to Git only when I need Git-specific services. I'm wondering how to get Git to track already-moved files in a single step, as with Mercurial's `addr`.

Comment: Ah, I see. `git add -A <path>` does appear to track both adds and removals in a single step. Thanks!